# effective parallelisation of bilinear interpolation using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I want to parallelise bilinear interpolation using OpenMP in such a way that there should be least memory access of input array. In the code below, for each iteration of i and j in output array, input data according to longitude and latitude values are read and processed.

- input[20][20] - input array that contains data values eg{1,2,3,..,400} in 2d
- lon[100][100] - longitudinal positions of each interpolation point in output array in horizontal axis not necessarily equidistant. eg. {2.34,2.65,2.74... }
- lat[100][100] -  latitudinal positions of each interpolation point in output array in vertical  axis not necessarily equidistant.eg. {5.76,5.92,6.26... }
- output[100][100] - array containing interpolated values

void interpolate(float (*lon)[100] ,float (*lat)[100] , float (*input)[20],float (*output)[100])
{

```
int i,j,floori,floorj;
float fractionj,fractioni;
for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        floori = lon[i][j];
        fractioni = lon[i][j] - floori;
        floorj = lat[i][j];
        fractionj = lat[i][j] - floorj;
        output[i][j] = (1.0-fractioni)*(1.0-fractionj)*input[floori][floorj] + fractioni*(1.0-fractionj)*input[floori+1][floorj] + (1.0-fractioni)*fractionj*input[floori][floorj+1] + fractioni * fractionj *input[floori+1][floorj+1];
    }
}
```

}

I need to divide the work in such a way that for all the interpolation points specified using lon and lat values within block of input[floori][floorj],input[floori+1][floorj],input[floori][floorj+1],input[floori+1][floorj+1] should go to one thread so that input values are read only once from memory to register for each thread.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it. Before you worry about performance at the cache level, parallelize it and measure how it performs. (Then, maybe consider collapse(2) to increase the available parallelism).

Comment: Thank you Jim, Actually I tried to parallelise the code as you have suggested and I have got significant performance boost, but I think if I go at cache level,performance will be even better.But I am facing problem in how to divide the work among threads, because threads should be assigned on the basis of floor and ceiling values of lat/lon, not on basis of i and j.

Comment: You can try the `shared` clause of OpenMP, which lets the parallel threads access the same variables in the cache. It would be helpful, if you would update your question with your parallel implementation.